# Why can't I truncate a table that is being referenced by a FK constraint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm trying to understand why SQL Server 2008 R2 complains when I try and truncate the table.

I have 2 tables:

- `Parent (id, ..)`
- `Child (id, parent_id, ..)`

The child table as a FK constraint (`parent_id`) to the `Parent` table.

Now if I try and do:

```
truncate table Child
truncate table Parent
```

It gives me the error:

> cannot truncate table 'Parent' b/c it is being referenced by a FK
>   constraint.

Even if I do a delete on both tables i.e. the tables are empty, I can't truncate the `Parent` table.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Truncate is more similar to dropping and re-creating the table than deleting the contents.  It doesn't make checks, etc, and so is prohibitted if clearing the data *could* breach any constraints.

Comment: SQL Server is a bit more severe than it needs to be here. Even if the FK constraint is disabled it does not allow this. [There is a workaround for that here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/251876/truncate-table-when-fk-are-disable)

Answer (score 0):

Truncate is DDL, not DML.

So if you truncate a table, you are telling the database to drop the table and recreate it.

Comment: TRUNCATE is DDL in the sense that it requires a schema lock and resets the current IDENTITY value to its seed. I'm not sure it makes sense to classify TRUNCATE as "not DML" however. It modifies data in a table just as DELETE does. SELECT INTO is a similar example of a statement with both DDL and DML aspects. In any case, saying it is DDL does not answer the question.